# Find all points where $f$ is differetiable

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, proof-verification

Let $$f(x) = \left\{ {\matrix{
   {0,x \notin Q}  \cr 
   {{x^2}({x^2} - 1),x \in Q}  \cr 
 } } \right.$$

I already proofed that $f(x_0)$ is continuous iff $x_0\in \left\{0,1,-1\right\}$.
Now, if $f$ is differentiable, it must be at those points.

Lets test $x_0=0$.

$$f'(x_0=0) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \frac{0}{0}$$.

Therefore, the derivative isn't defined at $x_0=0$.
Similarly, for $x_0=1,-1$.

I just wanna make sure I understood it right and I'm not mistaken somewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: $0/0$ is an indeterminate form, it is not necessarily undefined. If for instance you want to check that the function $f(x)=x$ is differentiable at $0$ then you get $f(x)/x \rightarrow 0/0$ however the limit exists and equals 1.

Comment: Oh of course. I should use L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Well to use L'hopital, you need to know that the numerator is differentiable, but that is what you are trying to prove. I'll leave an answer showing you a way to tackle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment. Near $0$, $x^2$ is positive and $x^2-1$ is negative, therefore near 0 $f(x) \leq 0$. Hence for $x>0$

$$ \frac{x^2(x^2-1)}{x}\leq\frac{f(x)}{x} \leq 0$$

Notice that $\frac{x^2(x^2-1)}{x} = x(x^2-1)$ for all $x\neq 0$ and so

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{x^2(x^2-1)}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} x(x^2-1) = 0$$

Hence by the sandwich (or squeeze) theorem, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 0$.

You can use the same technique to show that the left limit exists too. You have to do something different at $\pm 1$ because the function is not differentiable there.

Comment: Got it. Thank you @James

Comment: Message me if you need a hint for $\pm 1$

Comment: btw, suppose $f(x) = x^2(x^2-1)$ (ignoring the $0$ for irrationals). I could use  L'Hôpital's rule because $x^2(x^2-1)$ is polynomial and therefore differentaible on $\mathbb{R}$. Right?

Comment: It depends what you are trying to show. If you want to show that $f$ is differentiable, and you are allowed to claim that polynomials are differentiable, then why use L'Hopital's rule?